# class not found on move from 1.5.4 to 1.5.6 in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I updated my version of spring boot from 1.5.4 to 1.5.6 and now I am getting this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;)V
```

I see that some others reported this issue on 1.5.5 and 1.5.6 but they did not address a fix.

Any idea why this happens and what needs to change?

Comment: What version of Spring Data are you using? I would guess that you are overriding its version to something that is incompatible.

Comment: I am not explicitly defining a release version of spring data.  My various spring data components come in via starters.  I did run an effective pom on the project with this issue and I see that the spring data version is     <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Ingalls-SR6</spring-data-releasetrain.version>

Comment: Ok, that looks good as SR6 is the expected version. Something else is triggering the incompatibility. What other dependencies do you have and what's the full stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to the fact that *Spring Cloud Brixton.RELEASE* migrated from **spring-cloud-starter-parent** to **spring-cloud-dependencies** as its BOM for maven dependency management. It was working somehow until I tried to migrate spring boot from **1.5.4** to **1.5.6**. See **Notes** here - https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/11/spring-cloud-brixton-release-is-available

All I needed is to fix maven dependency management:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project this error occurs because maven included wrong versions of `spring-data-jpa` and `spring-data-commons` (perhaps somehow overwritten by one of the other dependencies we have).

I was able to fix it by explicitly defining the correct dependency versions in the `dependencyManagement` section.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- explicitly define correct spring-data-jpa and spring-data-commons versions -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      ...
</dependencyManagement>
```